# Object notation for DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

In following example, there is array-like object for DOM elements and there is one thing which is unclear to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    for(var prop in document.links){
        alert(prop); // It does not alert foo!
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a name="foo" href="#">foo</a>

</body>
</html>
```

In theory object notation for accessing prop is like: `obj.prop`.
In object array-like there must be number notation for elements of a object: `obj[0]`, and `obj.length`.

---

And alert is giving: `0`, `length`, `item`, `namedItem`. First two is from theory of object array-like and other two can be used for accessing props.

---

And, finally, this link could be found like `document.links[0]` and `document.links.foo`. There is no `foo` prop in `document.links`. Why? Thanks.

Comment: some of your confusion can be explained by the fact that document.links is an HTMLCollection, not an Array, and doesn't have the same methods as Array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `document.links.foo` is not available is because you're using `name` and not `id`.  If you change your markup to:

```
<a id="foo" href="#">foo</a>
```

Then [this will work](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/GaxrP/):

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.alert(document.links.foo.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Still, `document.links` does not have `foo` prop in itself, even with `id` attribute in link tag. Iterating through it, won`t alert `foo`...

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the DOM element itself to "alert()".  What about passing the "name" attribute?

```
for(var prop in document.links){
    alert(prop.name);
}
```

Now, it's really a bad idea to iterate through a node list like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; ++i)
  alert(document.links[i].name);
```

If you want the text content of the node, then you can try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; ++i)
  alert(document.links[i].innerHTML);
```

You could also find its child text nodes and extract their value.

Note that the "links" object will also include `<area>` tags, if you've got any.

Comment: My `alert` is giving: 0, length, item, namedItem. 0 is for first link tag, length for length of a given object array-like and those two are props too for accessing that tag. There is no `foo` prop in order to my logic of JS functionality to work.. :) And it is not a array.. :))

Comment: No, there's no "foo" property because there simply isn't one.  The "links" object is a NodeList, and it contains a list of the `<a>` element DOM nodes.  The property "name" in your example contains the value "foo".

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, but see this: `document.links.foo` is the link (DOM object), not sure if `document.links.name.foo` is..

Comment: That's because of the semantics of NodeList objects, I think.

Comment: @Pointy `for ... in` iterates over keys not values ._.